# Bug with line/circle collision in simple 2D physics sim

Tags: javascript, game-physics, game-engine, physics, physics-engine

I've just implemented line/circle collision into a simple physics simulation I'm working on, and there's a slight bug where when a ball falls off a line, the line sort of flings it away from under, I don't know exactly how to explain it, but to reproduce just click and drag to make an angled line and hover above the line and click space to spawn a ball and wait for it to roll off the line.

What could be causing this bug?

code: https://codesandbox.io/s/line-engine-verlet-ur0m1g

live demo: https://ur0m1g.csb.app/

Comment: I just solved the problem accidentally...